# How to import MS SQL dumps from Ruizata Project's SQL Server Dumper?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I used http://download.cnet.com/SQL-Dumper/3000-10254_4-10514574.html to make an sql dump of a database. How do I import the data into an empty database on a new server, without having to run the hundreds of .sql files manually?

Comment: @lad2025 Ruizata's SQL dumper does not come with restore, and SQL server management studio, does not seem to have an easy option to restore the hundres of .sql at once.

Comment: I mean do backup on one sql server, move it and restore on another.

Comment: @lad2025 I think you miss the entire point of the question! How do I restore the database after I made the backup using the sql server dumper?